# MySQL Workbench 'Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets: Timeout was reached'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Since I've updated MySQL Workbench to version 8.0.18 I can no longer connect to my Local instance. I am able to use MySQL via the command line. I have tried everything from changing passwords and making new users, but nothing seems to work.

[image: The error message I'm getting after clicking Local instance 3306:]